# Polymer 2 migration issues

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

Recently tried to migrate a Polymer1 app to Polymer2 but I am really having a hard time to get stuff working. Here are some things I noticed when trying:

- Do I really have to hand pick every paper/iron element for polymer2? I used to just install paper-elements and the like, this was a convenient way to simply get all components in a category, is there a similar way to get all paper-elements for polymer 2?
- The Api for paper-toolbar specifies a justify property that would center the content, but this does not seem to work in the case below:

```

```
<paper-toolbar class="tall" justify="center" bottom-justify="center">
  <div slot="top" class="title">Top Title</div>
  <div slot="middle" class="title">Middle Title</div>
  <div slot="bottom" class="title">Bottom Title</div>
</paper-toolbar>
```

```

- The fullbleed class on the body does not work anymore. I've included the iron-layout-classes and iron-layout files, but these do not have any effect :(

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

*Yes* you have to pick every paper/iron elements.

Elements have dependencies and you just need to install few of them to have a whole lot of polymer elements, I don't see the advantage of downloading a pack of elements when you will just not use them all anyways.

And the reason why `middleJustify` or `bottomJustify` are not working in your case is because you are using a `class="title"`. the toolbar will turn the slot `title` into a flex element, that means the element will stretch as far as possible to the right in the available space of its container. Because the title is taking all the available space justifying it to center will just fail (trying to center something that's all-contained in its container and it won't move).
If you want to justify to the center, try that :

```
<paper-toolbar class="tall" bottom-justify="center">
  <div slot="top" class="title">Top Title</div>
  <div slot="middle" class="title">Middle Title</div>
  <div slot="bottom">Bottom Title</div> <!-- remove the class title, not recommended for a title -->
</paper-toolbar>
```

or

```
<paper-toolbar class="tall" justify="center" bottom-justify="center">
  <div slot="top" class="title">Top Title</div>
  <div slot="middle" class="title">Middle Title</div>
  <div slot="bottom" class="title" style="text-align:center;">Bottom Title</div>
</paper-toolbar>
```

Comment: Well I really liked the `bower install paper-elements` option to get all the paper-elements with just one command and get most of the elements and dependencies for development. That was really convenient. Before distribution, vulcanization takes care of treeshaking the dependencies. But if that is not available anymore, that is too bad..    As far as the toolbar goes, thanks, makes total sense. How could I miss that :-)

Comment: Still leaves me with the `<body class="fullbleed">`, still havent got that working...